# how to calculate unite price after 1 unit

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can I calculate price of unit of product?

For example.

one unit product costs $3
if product is more than one unit, $1 will be added to the remaining each unit. e.g I have 4 units of product its price will be $6 because first unit costs $3 and $1 is added to the remaining every unit.

P.S the unit can be float not only integer

Comment: After countless re-reads, I still can't make sense of anything you wrote. Can you please rephrase the question using structured English?

Comment: So, to clarify, if `unit=0`, `price=0`, if `unit <= 1`, `price=3`, if `unit>1`, `price=3+'rounded up'(unit-1)`? Is that right? You don't need a loop to solve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to loop, its just a maths calculation. It seems you want to round up for any units.

```py
import math

def calculate_price(unit):
    unit = math.ceil(unit)
    return 3 + 1 * unit - 1 if unit else 0

units = [3.4, 0.68, 3, 0]
for unit in units:
    print(f"{unit=}, cost={calculate_price(unit)}")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
unit=3.4, cost=6
unit=0.68, cost=3
unit=3, cost=5
unit=0, cost=0
```

Comment: One point to note is that i didnt enforce any mathmatical operator precedence here cause its not need due to the fact we are multiplying by 1 and subtracting 1 so the result is the same regardles of the order its carried out but for completeness you prob should write it as `return 3 + 1 * (unit - 1) if unit else 0` to make it clear should your additional unit prices change to something other than 1

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
def calculate_unit(unit):
    sum = 0
    unit=np.ceil(unit)#get the closest biggest integer
    for i in range(int(unit)): #convert float to int so that range works
        if i < 1 or i == 1:
            sum += 3
    return (sum)

print(calculate_unit(0.5))
```

You can modify this to suit your exact needs...I agree with others that there are many simple ways to do it. This could be a starting point

Comment: This can only return 0, 3 or 6 as possible values.

Comment: `numpy` seems overkill and the function won't give the desired results.